# returnTrue and returnFalse functions in jQuery source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't help but notice there are two seemingly useless functions in the source code of jQuery (For v1.9.1, it's line 2702 and line 2706):

```
function returnTrue() {
    return true;
}

function returnFalse() {
    return false;
}
```

Which both are called quite often within jQuery. Is there a reason why they don't simply substitute the function call with a boolean `true` or `false`?

Comment: In addition to the below answers, there are probably also performance reasons for a single definition instead of anonymous functions all over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it was used like this:

```
stopImmediatePropagation: function() {
    this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnTrue;
    this.stopPropagation();
}
```

here `isImmediatePropagationStopped` is a query **method**. used like this `event.isImmediatePropagationStopped()`

of course, you can define a instance method, like:

```
event.prototyoe.isImmediatePropagationStopped = function() { return this._isImmediatePropagationStopped };

stopImmediatePropagation: function() {
    this._isImmediatePropagationStopped = true; //or false at other place.
    this.stopPropagation();
}
```

but you have to introduce a new instance property `_isImmediatePropagationStopped` to store the status.

with this trick, you can cut off bunch of instance properties for hold true/false status here, like `_isImmediatePropagationStopped`, `_isDefaultPrevented` etc.

so that, in my opinion, this is just a matter of code style, not right or wrong.

PS:  the query methods on event, like `isDefaultPrevented` , `isPropagationStopped`, `isImmediatePropagationStopped` are defined in DOM event level 3 sepc.

spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#Events-Event-isImmediatePropagationStopped

Comment: Then why not use change `isImmediatePropagationStopped` to be an instance property instead? So we can use it like `if (event.isImmediatePropagationStopped)` instead of `if (event.isImmediatePropagationStopped())`?

Comment: It is also part of W3C spec (don't know why you deleted the comment): http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#Events-Event-isImmediatePropagationStopped

Comment: because the api is defined by w3c: **http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#Events-Event-isDefaultPrevented**

Comment: @JimDeville I want to add more detail. but could not edit it, as more than five mins past.

Comment: Accepted for the w3c reference

Answer (score 12):

If an object property, function argument, etc expects a `function` you should provide a `function` not a `boolean`.

For example in vanilla JavaScript:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
/*
 * see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick
 * element.onclick = functionRef;
 * where functionRef is a function - often a name of a function declared 
 * elsewhere or a function expression.
 */
a.onclick = true;                        // wrong
a.onclick = returnTrue;                  // correct
a.onclick = function() { return true; }; // correct
```

Also, writing:

```
someProperty: returnTrue,
```

Is more convenient than writing:

```
someProperty: function(){
    return true;
},
```

Especially since they *are called quite often*.

Comment: Can you explain why can't you simply use `someProperty: true`?

Comment: `true` is different from a function which returns true. If some property or argument requires a function you cannot substitute it with the literal `true`.