# Why does jquery have a function "returnTrue()" and "returnFalse()" that just return true and false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/9434e03193c45d51bbd063a0edd1a07a6178d33f/src/event.js#L21-L27
There are two functions in event.js in jquery that return true and false:
from events.js

```
function returnTrue() {
  return true;
}

function returnFalse() {
  return false;
}
```

I know they are good. But I don't understand the reasoning for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745912/returntrue-and-returnfalse-functions-in-jquery-source this might Help You to understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look and see where they are used?

They are used as a stubs for assignments that need a function that returns a boolean.

For example on line 670 of the same document:

```
    this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;
```

isDefaultPrevented is a function.  Thus it needs a function that returns true as the default functionality.

Comment: Is it that making these assignments would save memory (albeit minimally) compared to, say, using `isDefaultPrevented = function() { return true; }` in several different places - because each time you'd be referencing a single function object, rather than creating a new one?

Comment: @Adam - It probably saves some memory or it might have been optimized to be the same by the compiler / interpeter. It also might be, (in some people's opinion) easier to read -- this code choice is mostly a matter of style -- IMHO it is good style because it is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Consider their usage:

```
// Events bubbling up the document may have been marked as prevented
// by a handler lower down the tree; reflect the correct value.
this.isDefaultPrevented = src.defaultPrevented ||
        // Support: Android < 4.0
        src.defaultPrevented === undefined &&
        src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ?
    returnTrue :
    returnFalse;
```

Do this or something similar across several functions. It's easier to type `returnTrue`, than have to spell out `function() { return true; }` every time, isn't it? Code reuse and readability.